# Not getting notifications using activity_notification

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, notifications, rubygems

I have an application which use the gem [acts_as_follower](https://github.com/tcocca/acts_as_follower) to user follow each other. I'm also using the [activity_notification](https://github.com/simukappu/activity_notification) to notify users about the app. In the acts_as_follower model I have:

**follow.rb**

```
class Follow < ActiveRecord::Base

  extend ActsAsFollower::FollowerLib
  extend ActsAsFollower::FollowScopes

  # NOTE: Follows belong to the "followable" interface, and also to followers
  belongs_to :followable, :polymorphic => true
  belongs_to :follower,   :polymorphic => true

  def block!
    self.update_attribute(:blocked, true)
  end

  # acts_as_notifiable configures your model as ActivityNotification::Notifiable
  # with parameters as value or custom methods defined in your model as lambda or symbol.
  # The first argument is the plural symbol name of your target model.
  acts_as_notifiable :users,
  # Notification targets as :targets is a necessary option
  # Set to notify to author and users commented to the article, except comment owner self
    targets: ->(follow, key) {
      ([follow.user] + follow.user.to_a - [follow.user]).uniq
    }

  tracked: true
  # Path to move when the notification is opened by the target user
  # This is an optional configuration since activity_notification uses polymorphic_path as default


end
```

But I'm not getting the notifications. Should I try

```
targets: ->(current_user, key) {
  ([current_user.follow] + current_userfollow.to_a - [current_user.follow]).uniq
}
```

Someone already worked with this gems before? How can I get this notifications working?

I'm using devise for users.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

The configuration of your notification targets `([follow.user] + follow.user.to_a - [follow.user]).uniq` is always a blank array.